# Embed Time to MediaCapture Element in UWP

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10

I'm using MediaCapture element for video capturing in UWP. However, I cannot find how can I embed this time element ([Screenshot is available at here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOZTY.png))
to the video. I'm using a Dispatcher to tick and show the time:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer(); // Timer for clock.
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); // timer ticks in one second.
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick; // Tick event handler.
    timer.Start(); // Start the timer.

 private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    DateTime_Text.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("G");// Printing datetime on page.
} // Show time in main screen with tick.
```

Are anyone knows how can I embed this Tick event to MediaCapture ?
 Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to add the timer to page while recording? Or you want to add the timer to the recorded video?

Comment: Hi, I want embed the timer's data to video as a watermark, same as security cameras. My timer ticks on the page already.